# Binance Websocket How to get data for two or more crypto

Tags: python, websocket

Please Help how to get websocket data for multiple crypto

```
    import websocket , json
pairs = [ 'fxsusdt', 'bnbusdt', 'btcusdt']
socket = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=bnbusdt@kline_1m'
def on_message(ws, message):
    # json_message = json.loads(message)
    # data = json_message['data']
        # candle = data['k']
        # candle_closed = candle['x']
        # close = candle['c']
        # high = candle['h']
        # low = candle['l']
        # volume = candle['v']
        print(message)
    
    def on_error(ws, error):
        print(error)
    def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
        print("### closed ###")
    def on_open(ws):
        print("Opened connection")  
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close,  )
    ws.run_forever()
```

Above code give live data for one crypto.
How to get data for more than one crpto.
If any reference video or tutorial available please post

Comment: Hey, you might try to initialize multiple streams within your string variable `socket` divided by / like stream?=stream1/stream2/stream3. 

Within one connection you can pass up to ~1k streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen to a single stream you must use `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/stream` format. In your case the link would be `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbusdt@kline_1m`

The url format you use is used for multiple streams, and the correct usage is `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=stream1/stream2/stream3` as [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4697878/vlad-rudskoy) stated.

You can combine different type of streams with the second format.

```
wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=bnbusdt@kline_1m/btcusdt@depth@100ms
```